# Accessing Netatalk/AFP Shares from OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: linux, macos, osx-snow-leopard, ubuntu-10.04, netatalk

Recently upgraded Ubuntu home server from 8.04 client to 10.04 server and reinstalled all services therein. One of them is a Netatalk daemon that I configured in a fashion similar to this website: http://www.kremalicious.com/2008/06/ubuntu-as-mac-file-server-and-time-machine-volume/

Finder recognizes my server and the afp service, yet when I attempt to log in (using valid credentials), Finder indicates its the wrong username and password. I've tried altering some of the config files and my Google-fu to look for solutions, but no luck. Any tips?

(This was not an issue under 8.04, if it matters)

Comment: ANSWER:
in the /etc/netatalk/afpd.conf file, the following had to be changed

Original
- - transall -uamlist uams_randnum.so,uams_dhx.so -nosavepassword -advertise_ssh
Fix
- - transall -uamlist uams_randnum.so,uams_dhx**2**.so -nosavepassword -advertise_ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "similar fashion" do you mean you compiled Netatalk with SSL?  Netatalk will not work with SL without encryption.

Could you sanitize (remove identifying info) from your afpd config files and include them in your question?  Chances are it's a config file issue if it's compiled with SSL.

Comment: Yes, I did compile netatalk w/SSL, because OS X 10.5+ requires it (if my understanding is correct). I just now found the answer, which required an extremely subtle modification in the /etc/netatalk/afpd.conf file, which I'll post as a comment in the original question. Thank you very much for responding, please an upvote! =D

Comment: Can't quite upvote you (not enough reputation), but thank you nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to fix the same problem in Ubuntu 11.10. The following site contains instructions that avoid having to manually recompile Netatalk yourself (there's a ppa repository for it now)

http://www.denoo.info/2011/12/ubuntu-11-10-network-shares-to-os-x-lion-with-netatalk/